# javascript date variable to zend date

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

How to change javascript date to zend date?
I'm sending throught ajax date in format:

```
Mon Nov 25 2013 12:00:00 GMT 0100
```

I'm trying like this:

```
$date_tmp = new Zend_Date($date, false, 'pl_PL');
print_r($date_tmp->get('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));die();
```

But in output I get:

```
2013-12-25 00:01:40
```

Insted of:

```
2013-12-25 12:00:00
```

Maybe timezone i wrong setup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug in `Zend_Date` when setting a time that crosses the DST change](http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-10584z).

Here's code that illustrates the problem:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo '<pre>';

// DST BEGINS '2012-03-11 02:00:00' - "Spring Forward"
$a = new Zend_Date('2012-03-11 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$a->setTime('04:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
echo $a->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'iso')
        . ' // expected: 2012-03-11 04:00:00' . PHP_EOL;
$b = new Zend_Date('2012-03-11 04:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$b->setTime('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
echo $b->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'iso')
        . ' // expected: 2012-03-11 00:00:00' . PHP_EOL;

// DST ENDS '2012-11-04 02:00:00' - "Fall Back"
$c = new Zend_Date('2012-11-04 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$c->setTime('04:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
echo $c->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'iso')
        . ' // expected: 2012-11-06 04:00:00' . PHP_EOL;
$d = new Zend_Date('2012-11-04 04:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$d->setTime('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
echo $d->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'iso')
        . ' // expected: 2012-11-06 00:00:00' . PHP_EOL;

echo '</pre>';
```

Ouputs:

```
2012-03-11 05:00:00 // expected: 2012-03-11 04:00:00
2012-03-10 23:00:00 // expected: 2012-03-11 00:00:00
2012-11-04 03:00:00 // expected: 2012-11-06 04:00:00
2012-11-04 01:00:00 // expected: 2012-11-06 00:00:00
```